# getting values from servlet to same html page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created 3 textboxes in HTML page and I gave 2 values for first two text boxes and send to a servlet and I want get result back in third text box. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share the servlet code written by you? Is it a homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use JSP. Forward request from servlet to jsp setting daat in attribute.

in Servlet

```
request.setAttribute("attrName","Value");
```

now forward this request to jsp, and on jsp access this `attrName` with

`${attrName}`

**See**

- [Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSP or AJAX,JavaScript to send the request to the servlet and receive the response to update the third textbox...